# PersistentCollection not initialized but data in database with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony

I have a problem with a PersistentCollection.

I have an Object User (herited of FOSUserbundle user class) who have an EmdebedDocument Seance. The Seance have an Array of Event. 
My Seance Class:

```
/**
* @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
*/
class Seance
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Event")
 */
protected $dispos ;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $rayonDeplacement;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $lieu;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $prix;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $nbPersonne;
```

And my class Event

```
/**
* @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
*/
class Event extends BaseEvent
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $startDate;
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $endDate;
```

I give the event from user with:

```
$user->getSeance()->getDispos()
```

This function returns a empty PersistentCollection while they are events in database.

When dump the return of getDispos() method I have:
[image: dump of result getDispos() method]

I dont't understant why I have mongoData field with my data but arrayCollection empty.

Thank you for yout help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PersistentCollection` is initialized lazily - for performance reasons, the data from database is held in `mongoData`. The collection is initialized during the first time you need some data from it (or try to modify it) - then the data held in `mongoData` is hydrated into your embedded documents and that is added to decorated `coll`. All this is happening transparently to you, just try using your collection instead of dumping it.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer. The problem that the document return is null hydrated with null value.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could happen, could you please try checking if `$user->getSeance()->getDispos()->first()` yields correct document?

Comment: Okey it's resolve I don't understand why the problem is resolve. Thank you for your help !